# Ruby on Rails Why doesn't my email confirmation work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, sendmail

**What I want to do:**

Send an email to a user confirming that they have successfully registered.

**What I have tried to do:**

I have followed this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

And so have ran the command: 'rails generate mailer UserMailer', and have added/edited the following files to look like this:

app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default sender: "ben@thorcinemas.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.first_name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.first_name %><%= @user.last_name %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.txt:

```
Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.first_name %>
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is: <%= @user.first_name %><%= @user.last_name %>.

To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

app/controller/users_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
      # accessible to all pages
       session[:user_id] = @user.id
       UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
       redirect_to films_path
    else
       render action: "new"
    end
  end
```

**Other Details:**

Rails version: rails 4.2.0

Operating System: Windows 7

I am connecting to the rails server through localhost:3000 - it is running on my own machine.

I have tried sending emails to a gmail and a tiscali account but neither have worked.

Schema.rb:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "role"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "house_no"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "town"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.string   "email"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
  end
```

Please note that I'm fairly new to Ruby. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "ben@thorcinemas.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

I changed default sender to default from and during testing, I'd also change deliver_later to deliver_now, instead of queuing it, it happens right away

And change this app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.txt to welcome_email.txt.erb

Also I'd setup gem letter opener, it's super easy to setup, it'll open emails on browser tabs and you'll get to see your emails, maybe that happens automatically in the version of rails you're using, but it's good to know.

Comment: Thanks, I've made those changes but it still does not work. Any other ideas? Could it be because I'm running rails on my own machine?

Comment: possibly, you'll need to configure it so that it emails are sent out locally, did you try letter opener?

Comment: @BenSmith have you changed the default mailer in your development environment? Also are you using a gem for user creation?